# Transforming an array in Python

Tags: python, graph

I am doing sentiment analysis on a text and it analyses sentiment on a sentence-to-sentence basis, and below is the result I got.

```
[1.0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0, 1.0]
```

I would like to plot a graph sentiment score against sentence number using Python, can anyone tell me how to do it?

Do I need to create another array like [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 15], something like that and plot it? If so, how can I do it in Python?

I have not much experience in Python nor programming, so I would really appreciate it if someone could help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an array or list for the `x` coordinates if you want, but it is not necessary. You can plot the values without giving `x` coords and in this case you will get them as a sequence starting from `0`.
Here is a simple example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
y=[1.0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0, 1.0]
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```